# How to Concatenate Mnist Test and Train Images?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a Generative Adversarial Network. To train the network I'm using mnist dataset. I will train the network with concatenated test and train images.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("data/mnist",one_hot=False)
images=np.concatenate(mnist.test.images,mnist.train.images)
```

An error has been occurred when I run the code.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-02ac414642a1> in <module>()
      3 from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
      4 mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("data/mnist",one_hot=False)
----> 5 images=np.concatenate(mnist.test.images,mnist.train.images)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

How to solve that or is there another way to concatenate `mnist.test.images` and `mnist.train.images` arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you should use `numpy.concatenate`. You can do it like this:

```
images = np.concatenate([mnist.test.images, mnist.train.images], axis=0)
```

If you go through the `numpy.concatenate` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), you will see that as a first argument the `numpy.concatenate` expects:

> a1, a2, … : sequence of array_like

Therefore, combining the `mnist.test.images` and `mnist.train.images` in an array as in the snippet above solves your problem. Additionally, even though the second argument `axis` default value is `axis=0`, I tend to specify it for clarity.